# Find out what device to use for capturing with ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, alsa

I'm trying to broadcast my screen and I cannot capture audio. There's one complication however. I don't have `pulseaudio`, and it simply doesn't work on my system, so installing it is out of question. Below is the command I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i ??? -f x11grab -s 1920x1200 -r 15 -i :0.0 \
    -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 \
    -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x800 -threads 0 -f flv "$URL"
```

Here's the list of my audio devices:

```
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC269VB Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
```

I know that `???` should be something like `hw:X,Y`, but maybe it can be something else. I can't find the corresponding entry in the man page.

As an aside, it would be great if you can suggest another audio codec. I can't find what are the options, and this particular one isn't compatible with FLV because of too high bitrate.

PS. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Please add some background data: OS (ffmpeg acts differently on various OSes), graphic UI used, are you are trying to capture system sounds, or you are adding it from file? And why are you using FLV for 1280x800?

Comment: @DavidJashi os is specified in the tags: it's Linux, in particular it is Fedora Core 18 amd64, KDE desktop manager. No graphic UI used. I'm trying to capture microphone. I'm using FLV to broadcast to Twitch (it's a site that allows sharing video in real time and it uses FLV to do it, or so I was told).

Comment: Use `arecord -l` to get a list of capture devices.

Comment: Oh, thanks, @CL. in the end I simply looked up `cat /proc/asound/cards`, and it gives me the list of cards, then I could use `hw:card,index` to direct it to the proper device. In my case it was `hw:PCH,0` and, yes, it would be possible to find this same information in the way you suggested.

Comment: You should always include the complete ffmpeg console output along with your command.

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, I saw Linux in tags, but believe me, sometimes even kernel build matters, when it comes to ffmpeg. About "No graphic UI used" - I meant is it KDE or Gnome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the currently active ALSA device by testing with aplay, like so

```
aplay -vv /path/to/sample.wav
```

Alternatively, you could explicitly configure a specific hardware device by setting it in `/etc/asound.conf`

The bitrate of the ffmpeg audio codec can be controlled via the `-ab` [parameter](http://www.itbroadcastanddigitalcinema.com/ffmpeg_howto.html)